# Phonegap - barcode scanner plugin - Class not found on real device

Tags: android, cordova, barcode, qr-code

For our current project we are required to scan QR-codes via our own application. We've looked into the possibilities and found that https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner was the best option. We made a basic testing application and it runs fine on the emulator.

But on a real andriod device we have problems as soon as we hit a button which should start scanning. An alert pops up with the message "Class not found."

We followed [this](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3) tutorial for our test application.

---

I found out the issue is with the phonegap cloud. It appears it doesn't support plugins. We'll have to build it for andriod and iOS then I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which API you are using to develop the barcode scanner app. My recommendation is you can use Zxing API. There are two ways of using this API:
1. You can call this API from your app as an Intent. If the zxing application is installed in your device then  the intent will launch the zxing app, else it will download from android market place.
2. You can extract the relevant code from the zxing code as this is open source.
Let me know the issues in the use of Zxing. I have done this.

There is another API called RedLaser. But this is not open source, you have to pay to use this. This is also reliable.

Comment: I'm using the Zxing API yes.
I found that the issue is with the phonegap cloud.